# ActiveMQ Artemis: Quorum-only instance?

Tags: cluster, high-availability, activemq

For a fully redundant ActiveMQ Artemis cluster, [either a set of three broker pairs or network ping is required](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/network-isolation.html) to avoid split-brain scenerios. In some installations, only two datacenters or availability zones are available plus a small third site for quorum servers.

Is it possible to run an Artemis broker as quorum-only instance that does not actually handle workload?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ActiveMQ Artemis does not support "quorum only" instances.

That said, development is underway to improve the requirements for this use-case.